# Interchanging a sum with an integral

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

Since the Haar system is a complete orthonormal system for $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ any $L$-square function $f$ can be written as a superposition of elements of the Haar system:
$$ f(x) = \sum_j \sum_k \langle f,h_{j,k} \rangle h_{j,k}(x) $$
where $$h_{j,k}(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      1 & x\in [\frac{k}{2^{j}},\frac{k+1/2}{2^{j}} )\\
      -1 & x\in [\frac{k+1/2}{2^{j}},\frac{k+1}{2^{j}} ) \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$$

Integration yields

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_j \sum_k \langle f,h_{j,k} \rangle h_{j,k}(x)dx = \sum_j \sum_k  \langle f,h_{j,k} \rangle \int_{\mathbb{R}} h_{j,k}(x)dx = 0$$
which is to say any any $L$-square function $f$ has zero integral over the real line which is pure nonsense. (We might as well take $f$ to be compactly supported but that doesn't change anything.) What have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points. First, not every function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is integrable. And second, on the subspace $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the integral is not continuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm. Since the series

$$f = \sum_{j,k} \langle f, h_{j,k}\rangle h_{j,k}$$

converges to $f$ in the $L^2$-norm, but usually not in the $L^1$-norm (if $f \in L^1\cap L^2$), one can in general not move the sum outside the integral.

Comment: So you're saying the interchange of the sum and integral is not allowed, because the convergence of the sum happens in L-square not in L-one and L-square convergence doesn't guarantee L-one convergence? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point.

Comment: Well then, lots of thanks Daniel :)